# Change events dynamically?

Tags: vba, excel

How do you programatically set events to a workbook. I have seen workbooks that have things such as ThisWorkbook.OnClose = "macronamehere" and this is very useful but I can't seem to replicate this in my Excel 2013 workbooks.

Summary: How do you set events to a specific macro using only the VBA language rather than the GUI drop down.

Reason: I would like to be able to do it this way because then it will also explain how I can create a workbook in VBA code and directly code the events to that newly created workbook as well as dynamically change my events in a different way.

Comment: I cannot imagine how this could possibly be of any use :( Could you be so kind as to give an example of a situation where this (if it is possible) would be beneficial?

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky I have actually seen events assigned in this way in other Excel sheets of earlier versions of Excel (2007 I think?) so I know that this is at least possible in those versions. I have a bunch of methods that I have created that are quite complex and I reuse them in other places. I might want to allow the operator of the Excel sheet to choose the behavior they want on open or on close or on right click from a configuration GUI. I know there is ways to do this in other ways but it is not to be able to reuse my methods directly by assigning them to the event.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky after explaining to you why I think this is useful I realized I could use Application.OnTime to accomplish this same behavior. But I am mainly asking this question because I have seen it done already and so it is nice to know how to do it and what are the limitations of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you employ Class Modules in order to achieve the desired result? I'll include an example below to give an idea of how they would work.

First, add a Class Module (Insert - Class Module), and enter the following code:

```
Private WithEvents xlApp As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set xlApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox ("I will remember you!")
End Sub
```

Next, we have to instantiate the new class, which we could do in a standard module. The code is as follows (note, Class1 is just the default name for a class, which you can, and should, change in the Class Properties Menu):

```
Private xlAppInstance As Class1

Sub LoadClass()
    Set xlAppInstance = New Class1
End Sub
```